# How to block a function to be used via object or class variable?

Tags: java

Here is a scenario "If I have a class 'calculator' which does Addition, multiplication, subtraction and division... I want to make another class "ScientificCalculator" that extends  'Calculator' but i don't want to use Multiplication and I want to make it sure that any other developer who uses my class 'ScientificCalculator' can not use multiplication" how can I achieve this functionality?

Ok I need it to more elaborate ...Calculator is not my class It was made by someone else I am just using it as a parent class of my class'Scientific Calculator'. I can't make any changes in Calculator.And I want anyone who use my class in future can't use Multiply method via object referencing to my parent class's multiplication method. –

Comment: You could throw an exception from the overridden `multiplication` method.

Comment: +1. This should be the way to go... Provided they will still be able to invoke multiply but it will cause an exception. But you still can't have the ScientificCalculator without multiply() operation.

Answer (score 3):

Do not extend your Calculator class. Create a ScientificCalculator class, provide the necessary methods. For those methods provided by Calculator, invoke the instance of Calculator, for others, write your own implementation.

```
public class Calculator {
    public double add(...) {}
    public double multiply(...) {}
    public double divide(...) {}
    public double subtract(...) {}
}

public class ScientificCalculator {
    Calculator c = new Calculator();
    public double add(...) { c.add(..) }
    //public double multiply(...) {}
    public double divide(...) { c.divide(..) }
    public double subtract(...) { c.subtract(..) }
    // .. other methods
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the following...

Create an interface `BaseCalculator` with only 3 operations.

```
interface BaseCalculator{
  public double add(...) {}
  public double divide(...) {}
  public double subtract(...) {}
}
```

Then implement the same in you remaining classes.

```
public class Calculator implements BaseCalculator {
   public double add(...) { }
   public double divide(...) { }
   public double subtract(...) {}       
   public double multiply(...) {}
}

public class ScientificCalculator implements BaseCalculator {
   public double add(...) { }
   public double divide(...) { }
   public double subtract(...) {}
}
```

Using this a `ScientificCalculator` object will not have a way to invoke multiplication.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Alternate approach,

By using final keyword to prevent method overriding.

```
public class Calculator {
   public double add(...) { }
   public double divide(...) { }
   public double subtract(...) {}       
   public final double multiply(...) {}
}

public class ScientificCalculator extends Calculator {
   //other methods here
}
```

Comment: Using the `final` keyword will prevent you from overriding the method, but the class can still be extended and the method can still be invoked. The question is about how to prevent the the method be invoked, not about how to prevent it from being overriden.